# Django leaflet marker icon doesn't appear on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-leaflet

I have deployed my Django app to Heroku but when I want to fill the location field, the marker icon doesn't appear even though I have used whitenoise to serve the static files. It is working locally though.
This is the [image]

Here's how I set my whitenoise

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Note:

The circle marker works fine

Comment: Please can you show me you root project files? I'm looking for certain tell tale signs.

Comment: here https://github.com/ragunggg/cvrp

Answer (score 0):

Have you been through this section of the django heroku tutorials?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration

You need to specify certain files so that heroku automatically tried to collectstatic files

Comment: for some reason it broke my server when I tried it

Comment: Did you check the heroku logs? Can you also post them?

Comment: nothing particular, it just gave status=500. It was also occurred to me back when I didn't use whitenoise to serve static files

Comment: when I inspect on the browser, the source of the marker icon is kinda weird. It get it from src=http://cvrp-bandung.herokuapp.com/static/leaflet/images/marker-icon.2273e3d8ad92.png")marker-icon.png

Comment: Ok then maybe its your js/jquery initialisation of the map then?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, except I deployed on DigitalOcean. I couldn't find any info on that matter, so I came up quick and dirty solution: I just created those images, that Leaflet was trying to get (see screenshot below).

I know, that it's not a good solution, but I just needed some quick fix, so I'm OK with that. I also noticed, that in my dev env (which is Windows, btw), not only everything worked, but `python manage.py collectstatic` collected much more leaflets' images, than it did in my prod env (which is Ubuntu). I'm using **the same versions** of django-leaflet (0.29.0) and **in the same virtual env** (conda with Python3.9). Very strange.

[image: creating images]